# AngularJS, how to use capturing groups in Regex

Tags: angularjs, regex

In my project, a user can enter a string, which is  then translated in the view to a button.

Here is an example, for what I wish to happen:

User types in: `argumentation-link_to(80)`

In the view, it should look like this:

```
<button ng-click="goToArgumentation(80)" 
  class="btn btn-xs btn-info"> a link 
</button>
```

This is my code right now:

```
$scope.buttonmaker = function(haystack) {

    needle = /argumentation-link_to\(\d+\)/i; // <-- Regex

    haystack = $sanitize(haystack);

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(haystack.replace(new RegExp(needle, "gi"), function(match) {
        console.log(match);
        return '<button ng-click="goToArgumentation(' + match[0] + ')" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"> a link </button>'
    }));
};
```

At the moment, `argumentation-link_to(80)` will produce this:

```
<button ng-click="goToArgumentation(a)" 
  class="btn btn-xs btn-info"> a link 
</button>
```

I need to get the number `80` in `argumentation-link_to(80)` to fill in the argument in `goToArgumentation()`

Thankfully, Regex gives us the option to retrieve data within the Regex with capturing groups. However, when I try to use them, I get the error, that the regex is not valid. [Using this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refext.html), I tried:

```
/argumentation-link_to\((?<id>\d+)\)/i
/argumentation-link_to\((?'id'\d+)\)/i
```

Here I tried one, where no error occured, but I could not get the value:

```
/argumentation-link_to\((?:\d+)\)/i
```

What is the correct way to use capturing groups in angular js? And how would I reference them?

Comment: Use `/argumentation-link_to\((\d+)\)/i` and access via `match[1]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If I do this, it returns: <button ng-click="goToArgumentation(r)" 
  class="btn btn-xs btn-info"> a link 
</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use capture groups you use () and the the exec() function of RegExp:

```
$scope.buttonmaker = function(haystack) {

    needle = /argumentation-link_to\((\d+)\)/i; // <-- Regex

    haystack = $sanitize(haystack);

    return $sce.trustAsHtml(haystack.replace(new RegExp(needle, "gi"), function(match) {
        console.log(match);
        return '<button ng-click="goToArgumentation(' + needle.exec(match)[1] + ')" class="btn btn-xs btn-info"> a link </button>'
    }));
};
```